# Using Inner classes correctly (how to share class in user event)

Tags: java, inner-classes

I am trying to program a java application that consists of several windows using JFrame.

Each JFrame contains a JTextField and buton to go to the next JFrame.

I need to retrieve all the information entered by the user at the end.

I created an event click on the buton to save to a public class all the data that the user introduce in the JTextField. I named that public class myData, which has a static attributes.

The problem is that I can not access this class from the button listener function.

I get an error: cannot refer to an non final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method.

My goal is to be able to share the class myData between different methods of a different class.

E.g. I have a class named myClass1 and myClass2, so I want to share the myData attribute between myClass1 methods and myClass2 methods.

Please anyone can someone help me? or propose another way to do this!

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the calls about MVC etc. are valid, but this isn't that hard.

What you want to do is in your Main, you can create your Data (Model) class, the class that holds all of your information.

So, you can do something like this:

```
public class F1 ... {
    private final Data myData;

    public F1(Data theData) {
        myData = theData;
    }

    ....
}

public class Main {
    Data myData;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.setMyData(new Data());

        F1 f = new F1(m.getMyData());
        ...
     }
}
```

Then, later, when F1 calls F2, simply do the same thing -- create F2 with the Data passed in earlier by the constructor. That way, as each Frame runs its course, they're all working on the same instance of Data. When all is done, the single instance of Data is left within the Main class for you to do with what you will.

There are better ways to reorganize your entire program, but this should give you ideas on how to get over the hump you're having right now.

Addenda:

There are several things you can do.

When your get the ActionEvent, it contains a source. That source is the component that generated the event (most likely a Button in this case). If you know where the button is located in the hierarchy of things, you get to your Frame directly. In the pastebin example, you have Frame -> Panel -> Button. So, if you have the Button, you cat get to the Frame.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton sourceButton = (JButton)e.getSource();
    F1 f1 = (F1)sourceButton.getParent().getParent();
    Data myData = f1.getMyData();
    data.setField(...);
}
```

Again, this is not the recommended ways of doing things. The tutorials have decent examples of using MVC and property change listeners and the whole kit. But this should get you to where you want to go.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
but I still have the same problem, I can't have access to myData in the ActionPerformed function !!!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but your design needs alot of work. I'm going to recommend you read up on [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). it may seem like alot to chew on right now but it will help you immensely in the long run. On a side note, dont nest your data class definition(s), and remember to always distinguish between ***classes*** and ***objects***.

Comment: @user1055404: Note that Perception's suggestion is a darn good one. You may not be at a point where you will fully understand this yet, but if not now, then soon, and the general MVC principles have utility for many different programming tasks and languages. 1+

Answer (score 0):

Your overall design of swapping JFrame's seems a bit iffy to me. Why not instead use either dialogs such as a JDialog or JOptionPane or even better a CardLayout to swap views. Also I urge you not to use static fields for any of this as this can cause significant problems in the future and makes your code less compliant with good object oriented principles. With regards to information sharing, about all I can say is that it's all about one class having the proper reference to the other class. For more specific advice you'll likely need to show us more information and code.

**Edit**
Also, you know of course that you can get a reference to the JButton that stimulated the ActionListener by calling `getSource()` on the ActionEvent object passed into the `actionPerformed` method. This may allow you to get a reference to the class that holds the JButton if necessary.

Comment: @user1055404: Again I would use either a JOptionPane or a CardLayout for something like this.

Comment: I have three Jframes, JF1, JF2 and JF3. in Jf1 the user will introduce his data such as his name ... and when he click on a button the Jf1 will dispose and JF2 will appear, in JF2 the user will choose some options and by clicking on button the JF2 will dispose and JF3 will appear will all the previous data chosen in Jf1 and Jf2. 
that why I used the public class myData to store the user choices.
but I cannot access to the attributes in the actionperformed funcion.
may I show you the code ?

Comment: sorry but my code is too long.
any way, there's no way in java to have a global class that I can see from any other class ???

Comment: @user1055404: you don't want a global class. Consider using [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: MainClass calls F1 class that shows a Jframe, when I click on Button "empezar", F1 dispose, and F2 will appear.
what I pretend to do is to recuperate the value of the JtextFields on F1 and F2 from the MainClass.